# Consume method is not being called using MassTransit with Azure Service BusTopics in a .Net microservice application

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, .net-6.0, masstransit

I know that this is being asked a lot, but I already visited a lot of question and I'm in the dark at the moment.

I'm using 2 different apps, one is the producer and the other one is the consumer. The applications are using topic-subscription type.

Producer:

```
services.AddMassTransit(serviceCollectionConfigurator =>
            {
                serviceCollectionConfigurator.AddBus(registrationContext => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(configurator =>
                    {
                        configurator.Host("connectionString");

                        configurator.Message<CreateEvent>(configTopology =>
                        {
                            configTopology.SetEntityName("topic1");
                        });    
                    }
                ));    
            });
```

Consumer:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<CreateConsumer>(); //Consumer class
                x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("connectionString");

                    cfg.Message<CreateEvent>(configTopology =>
                    {
                        configTopology.SetEntityName("topic1");
                    });

                    cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<CreateEvent>("subscription1", e =>
                    {
                        e.PrefetchCount = 100;
                        e.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100;
                        e.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                        e.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

                        e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(100, 200, 500, 800, 1000));
                        e.UseInMemoryOutbox();

                        e.ConfigureConsumer<CreateConsumer>(context);
                    });
                });
            });
        }

public class CreateConsumer: IConsumer<CreateEvent>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CreateEvent> context)
        {
            //breakpoint here
        }
    }
```

One of the errors I spotted was the namespace of **CreateEvent** needs to be the same. When the producer publish the message I can't see the message being sent to azure, neither being received in the consumer.

I assume the problem can be located in both configurations but I have no clue. Any thoughts?

Edit: Forgot to mention I'm using masstransit v8, it seems by default they inject the hosted service to run the bus automatically.

Comment: Look at the logs from the consumer application, if you see SKIP the message type does not match what the consumer is expected. You can also view the Azure portal to make sure the topic has a subscription that's used by the consumer service.

Comment: I tried reproducing your issue but your code works on my end. Maybe you can try recreating your namespace it could have been misconfigured during your initial configurations. (Since masstransit doesn't delete old topics/queues).